# SQL: Get records that satisfy conditions coming from multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's take a simple table that links customer IDs to product IDs if the customer bought a certain product. I'm looking for an SQL (MySQL) that lists all customers who bought specific products.

```
CustomerID  ProductID
    1          A         // customer 1 bought product A
    2          A
    1          B
    3          A
    2          C
    3          B
```

I would like to get a list of customers who bought **both** A and B (customers 1 and 3) and customers who bought A but not B (customer 2). I need to do this for more than 2 products, about up to 10, like "A and C and D but not B and E and F".

Comment: The second part of the question with 10 products is not clear. Can you give more details or examples on how inclusion/exclusion of customers will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For question: `get a list of customers who bought both A and B`

```
SELECT  CustomerID
FROM    CustomerList
WHERE   ProductID IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP   BY CustomerID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

if uniqueness was not enforce on `ProductID` for every `CustomerID`, `DISTINCT` keyword is required,

```
SELECT  CustomerID
FROM    CustomerList
WHERE   ProductID IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP   BY CustomerID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID ) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*both queries*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb59f/2)

For the second question, *"..A and C and D but not B and E and F"*

```
SELECT  CustomerID
FROM    CustomerList
WHERE   ProductID IN ('A', 'C', 'D')
GROUP   BY CustomerID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3 AND
        CustomerID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT  CustomerID
            FROM    CustomerList
            WHERE   ProductID IN ('B','E','F')
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bb59f/1)

Comment: Case 1 does not work if a customer bought product A twice and product B never.

Comment: @juergend I agree, that's why in the second case, I added `distinct` if uniqueness was not enforce.

Comment: Well explained and adapted this answer easily for my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TRy this::

```
Select DISTINCT CUSTOMERID from table1 where PRODUCTID='A'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach for this one(test1 is your example table) :

```
Select customerId, group_concat(ProductId)
, case when (group_concat(ProductId) like '%A%' and group_concat(ProductId) like '%B%') then 'Bought A&B'
when (group_concat(ProductId) like '%A%' and group_concat(ProductId) not like '%B%') then 'Bought A only' end as Flag
        from test1
        group by customerId
```

Answer (score 0):

JW's answer works perfectly, I'd just like to make a small addition. I used a simplified example in the question, in the original case the filtering happens on several joined tables. Taking that to this simple example it basically means that ProductID can be NULL. The query works, but runs for 2 minutes. It seems the cause is a [MySQL query optimization bug](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/). Changing the subquery condition to

```
  WHERE ProductID IS NOT NULL and ProductID IN('B','E','F')
```

reduced query time to two seconds.