# select from multiple rows with a column having same value and another column having different values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter, i want to select data from a table which has two columns lab_id and service_id

```
lab_id        service_id
  1              1
  1              2
  3              1
```

and i only want to select lab_id "1" which has both 1 and 2 as service id.
currently i am using following code but not working.

```
<pre>    
    $this->db->select('lab_id');
    $this->db->from('labs_services_mapping');
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $this->db->where('service_id',$value['id']);
    }
    $this->db->group_by('lab_id');
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
</pre>
```

$data is an array with service_id

Comment: I'm not clear on your question... are you asking "Give me all the service_id that belong to lab_id = 1?

Comment: which version of CI r u using ?

Comment: This is how to do this in raw sql, you need to replicate this via CI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835190/sql-get-records-that-satisfy-conditions-coming-from-multiple-records

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I want to select lab_id which has service_id as 1 and 2

Comment: Is this foreach loop mandatory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
$this->db->select('lab_id');
$this->db->from('labs_services_mapping');
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $this->db->or_where('service_id',$value['id']);
}
$this->db->group_by('lab_id');
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

you can try to use `where_in` too

```
$this->db->select('lab_id');
$this->db->from('labs_services_mapping');
$this->db->where_in("service_id", $data);
$this->db->group_by('lab_id');
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Since you want a static result you should do this

```
$this->db->select('lab_id');
$this->db->from('labs_services_mapping');
$this->db->where_in("service_id", [1,2]);
$this->db->group_by('lab_id');
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: These will return lab_id =3 as well.

Comment: print out your data array and add it to your post pls - because the query above should do what i said

Comment: @sintakonte contents of $data are <pre> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" } [2]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" } } </pre>

Comment: @sintakonte i want only those entries lab_id which has 1 and 2 service_id.

Comment: the question is - do you want to do that in a  static way ? because based on your output its pretty much clear that you get all 3 results - nevertheless i updated my answer - but i dont understand this purpose :P - in order to understand what you want you should post your entire model . (btw: i dont understand the downvote here ...)

Comment: @sintakonte working in static way but i want it for the service_id that are in $data array

Comment: @sintakonte i am doin this because i have a list of labs and list of services. the user selects multiple services and sends the request then in response i have to send him the only labs which provide all the services selected i.e each lab should provide all the services selected.

Comment: yeah its fine - but your data array contains the values 1,2,3 so something is wrong - because you said there has been only 1 and 2 selected - that was the reason for me asking you to show the entire model code